# I have a two routers, and the one is static and has 3 PCs connected to it also I have DHCP server

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, multiple-computers

Scenario:

[image]

Router2 is static

I wanna ask what is the supposedly IP address, default gateway, DNS1, and sub of PC1 to PC3.

Comment: Impossible to answer. Which drawn connections represent which interfaces on the router? Does the DC have a separate interface or is it connected to same switch as PCs?

Comment: The ip addressing will depend on who contacts the DHCP server first, so if PC1 is first it will get 192.168.5.100 and if PC2 is then second it will get 192.168.5.101.

Comment: The DHCP/DC are separated and only connected to the Router2. My prof ask what must be the IP addresses, Gateway, subnet, and DNS1, DNS2 if all the PC will get IP from DHCP server provided the Router2 is static. @grawity

Comment: The DHCP/DC are separated and only connected to the Router2. My prof ask what must be the IP addresses, Gateway, subnet, and DNS1, DNS2 if all the PC will get IP from DHCP server provided the Router2 is static. @Bungicasse

Comment: Sorry I will not help you with your homework.

Comment: That...didn't make it any clearer, sorry. Your drawing does not have enough information to answer this.

Comment: Providing the IP is not enough, you must also provide the network mask.

Answer (score 0):

The WAN would typically be the connection to the Internet.  However, in this drawing, it looks like Router2's connection to the Internet is Router1, and they would likely be communicating using 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2, not the WAN address.  So that doesn't seem to be making sense.

DNS isn't mentioned in the chart at all, and might be the domain controller 192.168.5.10 or a public one like 8.8.8.8.

Subnet size can be nearly any valid size, like 255.255.255.0 or 255.255.255.240 or maybe 255.255.255.248, allowing any device to communicate with any other device.  Smaller subnets like 255.255.255.252 may be possible for parts of the network.

The default gateway is typically the nearest router that is closer to the Internet.  So, for PC 1 through PC 3, the default gateway would be Router 2.

I'm guessing the DHCP server hands out 192.168.5.100 through 192.168.5.200 but that is basically just a guess based on the diagram.  The DHCP server might be able to hand out addresses in the 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.200 range, depending on how traffic is handled.  (DHCP Relay might be needed for such an implementation.)

If you're seeking actual help for a real implementation, understand that IP addresses are often assigned to individual network ports.  If you show every network port, the diagram may be more comprehendable.